# Issue in Static and non-static context in java

Tags: java

Example 1

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    static double angle=10.0; //or non-static
    public double getangle(){
    return angle;
}
public static void main(String []args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World "+getangle());
}
```

The above code is generating the following error:

```
HelloWorld.java:7: error: non-static method getangle() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Example 2

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Myscanner
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter your name: ");
String name=sc.next();
System.out.println("enter your age: ");
int age=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter your salary: ");
double sal= sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("name is "+name+"    age is "+age+"      salary is "+sal);
}
}
```

In Example 2 `'sc.next()'` is a non static method and it is referenced from a static context which is main method. But Example 2 executes without any error! Why? can anyone please explain me?

Comment: Learn java and read the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1:**

Though the field is static the method you are calling is a non static method and need instance for that to access. Hence the error.

**Case 2:**

You have instance of Scanner  in your static context  and you can access to those instance methods. So no error.

Comment: Well that was basic. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @kanthandres Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not reference `next()` in a static context.  You call it through an instance, so its context is the object on which it is called (`sc.next()`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

1. In your 1st case, the `getangle` method is an instance method of the class, but you try to invoke it from a `static` method of the class. 
   Hence, the error as `static` context cannot know about instances for the same class.
2. In your 2nd case, you are calling an instance method of an `Object` initialized within the context of the `static` method, so it's perfectly legal to invoke its instance methods.

In other words...

1. The **instance** fields and methods of a given class are not accessible to the `static` methods and statements of that given class.
2. The instance fields and methods of an `Object` initialized within **any** context are accessible within that context (if the access modifiers allow it of course).

Answer (score 0):

**non-static method getangle() cannot be referenced from a static context**

Example -1 :

`getAngle()` is defined at *instance level* for class `HelloWorld` so, you need an instance of `HelloWorld` to access it.

**'sc.next()' is a non static method and it is referenced from a static context which is main method. But Example 2 executes without any error! Why? can anyone please explain me?**

Example -2 :

`next()` method is defined at *instance level* for a `Scanner` Object and you are creating a new instance of Scanner object 
`Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);` and using it like this : `sc.next();`

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, you are trying to call `getAngle` without having instantiate any `HelloWorld` object, resulting if an error (since `getAngle` is not static).
In Example 2, you do instantiate a `Scanner` object called `sc`, so there is nothing wrong calling `sc.next()` event if `next` is not static.

Answer (score 0):

In Example 1, you have no reference to any `HelloWorld` object, and therefore can't access any of its member variables or methods.

In Example 2, you have a reference `sc` to the `Scanner` object and can therefore use `sc` to access any of its public instance methods.